# Why doesn't this Image Swap work

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm completely new to Jquery and Javascript and I was looking for a way to swap two different images on hover. So far nothing happens... So my question is why doesn't this Jquery Function Swap Images on hover.

```
 jQuery(function(){
     $(".nav-button").hover(
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png","http://i1256.photobucket.com/albums/ii488/terafanb/guildwars2/26.png");},
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("http://i1256.photobucket.com/albums/ii488/terafanb/guildwars2/26.png","http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png");
     });
});
```

Here the html that its manipulating.

```
<ul id="nav">
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
              <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="31" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="32" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="32" alt="" /></li>
               <li class="nav-button"><img src="http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u381/dice027/nyan-cat.png" width="225" height="30" alt="" /></li>
         </ul>
```

Full disclosure I got the design for the function here http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/quick-and-easy-jquery-image-swap/

And this is where I'm testing the function 
http://codepen.io/Austin-Davis/pen/IpDLu

Comment: this isn't in the correct scope. this.src in your code is the src for the LI, not the IMG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your element matched by `".nav-button"` isn't an image. So `this` has no property `src`.

Use this :

```
 $(".nav-button img").hover(
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` is referring to the `$(".nav-button")` as opposed to the `$(".nav-button img")`. A better way of changing the `src` is to use the `.attr()` method.

Comment: How is using the `attr` method better ?

Comment: I've used both and found the attr() more reliable.